# discriminate basic and advanced slicing of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm reading the doc about [numpy array indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), but still unclear about how to discriminate basic and advanced slicing.

Thanks if someone could explain a bit.

> `x[(1,2,3),]` is fundamentally different than `x[(1,2,3)]`. The latter is
>   equivalent to `x[1,2,3]` which will trigger basic selection while the
>   former will trigger advanced indexing. Be sure to understand why this
>   occurs.
>
> Also recognize that `x[[1,2,3]]` will trigger advanced indexing, whereas
>   x[[1,2,slice(None)]]` will trigger basic slicing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a simple 1d array:

```
In [326]: x=np.arange(10)
```

These 2 expressions do the same thing - select 3 elements from the array.  I could also verify that they return a copy, where as `x[1:4]` returns a view.

```
In [327]: x[(1,2,3),]
Out[327]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [328]: x[[1,2,3]]
Out[328]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

But without the command, the tuple raises an error:

```
In [329]: x[(1,2,3)]
...
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Same as:

```
In [330]: x[1,2,3]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

`x[1,2,3]` is converted by the Python interpreter into an call `x.__getitem__((1,2,3))`.  That is, the input values are passed as a tuple to a method.  The extra `()` in `x[(1,2,3)]` make no difference.  But the comma in the first expression adds a layer of nesting:

```
In [338]: ((1,2,3))
Out[338]: (1, 2, 3)

In [339]: ((1,2,3),)
Out[339]: ((1, 2, 3),)
```

`x[[1,2,slice(None)]]` is equivalent to `x[1,2,:]`, but I'll have to make a 3d array to verify this.

```
In [344]: X=np.arange(64).reshape(4,4,4)
```

3d indexing of a single element:

```
In [345]: X[(1,2,3)]
Out[345]: 27

In [346]: X[1,2,3]
Out[346]: 27
```

3d, with slice on last dimension:

```
In [347]: X[1,2,:]
Out[347]: array([24, 25, 26, 27])
```

The interpreter only accepts the `:` notation in square indexing brackets:

```
In [348]: X[(1,2,:)]
...
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But with `slice` we can write that as a tuple or list

```
In [349]: X[(1,2,slice(None))]
Out[349]: array([24, 25, 26, 27])

In [350]: X[[1,2,slice(None)]]
Out[350]: array([24, 25, 26, 27])
```

Tuple works here for the same reason that it did with `(1,2,3)`.  I think that it is treating the `[]` case the same way simply because that's the only thing that makes sense.  Combining numbers with a slice to make an advanced index does not make sense.

There is an indexing trick that lets me pick 2 items plus a slice:

```
In [354]: x[np.r_[1,3, 6:10]]
Out[354]: array([1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

but that is actually expanding the slice into a range

```
In [353]: np.r_[1,3, 6:10]
Out[353]: array([1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```